# How can I auto refresh my listview in Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am implementing custom listview using Base Adapter after entering the data my list is not refreshed automatically. I need to reopen the fragment to see the update.

```
public class Lead_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Lead_Model> leadarrayList;

public Lead_Adapter(Context context,ArrayList<Lead_Model>arrayList){

    this.context = context;
    this.leadarrayList = arrayList;

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.leadarrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return leadarrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convert_view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convert_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lead_listview, null);
    TextView Company_Name = convert_view.findViewById(R.id.company_name_listview);
    TextView Lead_Status = convert_view.findViewById(R.id.lead_status_listview);
    TextView Lead_Date = convert_view.findViewById(R.id.lead_date_listview);

    Lead_Model leadModel = leadarrayList.get(position);
    Company_Name.setText(leadModel.getCompany_name());
    Lead_Status.setText(leadModel.getLead_status());
    Lead_Date.setText(leadModel.getDate());
    return convert_view;
}
```

Comment: `after entering the data` how are you doing this\/

Comment: set swipe refresh to refresh list

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko To see upadte I need to reopen the fragment

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko To see upadte I need to reopen the fragment

Comment: after adding data to leadarrayList,you need notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: How you do `entering the data`?

Comment: I am entering the data within activity and after click submit button, I press the back button to see the list view the listview is showing on fragment  if I want to see changes I need to reopen the fragment

Comment: Trivia: if you write android refreshing data in listview, there will be a result for your question.

Comment: you need to make the ListView know that there is some new data. It won't understand it in a magical way itself.

Answer (score 2):

after adding your data into the adapter in your fragment do like this

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: @TARUNSHARMA    please accept answer and upvote if it is helpful.

Comment: Please never ask to upvote your answer. It is not up to you to choose whether it is good or not. If it is good, then it will naturally be upvoted by community

Answer (score 1):

You can call [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) when you finishing up adding your data.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding items into arrayList in your fragment you have to do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

just notify the list once you done with entering the data, no need to reopen the fragment.

```
items.clear();
items = db.getItems(); // fetch items from database
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```